# rich text editor does not work

Tags: wysiwyg

I am still stuck with the same problem. CKeditor doenot work, instead the plain text editor gets open. I tried everything from re-installing ckeditor to updating drupal to newer version.when I open any heading and try to open the edit option, it runs very slow. then when it gets open the data is visible in the form of plain text(no ckeditor), i checked the console it shows this error **Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience in drupal** Please can anybody help

Comment: Are you using modal forms or something and which profile you selected for ckeditor?

Comment: i am using full and advanced both. still it doesnot work